# Perforce superuser is lost

Tags: version-control, perforce

I am using a Perforce server but the only superuser account is lost due to the fact that the Perforce support guy (who use the superuser account) left the company and did not write down the superuser account details. My team is depending on the perforce server. What can I do now to regain administration control of it ?  I do have administrative right of the Windows server that is hosting the perforce server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick search on the internet reveals that Perforce gets asked about that a lot, and they did something about it: here is a [link](https://community.perforce.com/s/article/2492) to their knowledge base article.

Here is the description of te problem from the article:

> The super user is unable to access the Perforce database due to the following conditions:
>
> - When the only super user account listed in the protections table is accidentally deleted, but still remains in the protections table
> - The owner of the super user account forgets the super user account password

The idea behind the fix is to stop the server, move `db.protect` out of the way, bounce the server, change the password using any other account, then move `db.protect` back, and bounce the server again.